# How to perform normalization in my data if i'm using the keras method Flow_from_firectory

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to normalize my data with the mean and standard deviation as this example:

```py
datagen.fit(data)
mean = datagen.mean  
std = datagen.std

print(mean, "mean")
print(std, "std")
```

Before that, in my predict file I will put the 2 values (mean and std) to call this method:

```py
def normalize(x, mean, std):
    x[..., 0] -= mean[0]
    x[..., 1] -= mean[1]
    x[..., 2] -= mean[2]
    x[..., 0] /= std[0]
    x[..., 1] /= std[1]
    x[..., 2] /= std[2]
    return x
```

But in my train file I'm using the method flow_from_directory to get the data:

```py
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        zoom_range=0.2,
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        featurewise_center=True,
        featurewise_std_normalization=True,)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(TRAIN_DIR,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=50,
    class_mode='binary')
```

My doubt is: If I don't have the 'x_train' array, how could I pass in `datagen.fit(data)`?

I'm doing it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate *mean* and *std* by yourself. After that just set these values to the DataGenerator:

```
datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=True,
                               featurewise_std_normalization=True)
datagen.mean = np.array([111.1, 222.2, 333.3], dtype=np.float32).reshape((1,1,3))
datagen.std = np.array([5.3, 4.2, 6.3], dtype=np.float32).reshape((1,1,3))
```

Comment: Did you setted these values randomly?

Comment: And what means the reshape?

Comment: Can answer me ?